# Strange character at the beginning of logging - C

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to log whenever a user does something into a log file, with the date included, however when I do this, at the beginning of each log, I get a strange symbol.

```
        char log[200];
        char datetime[200];
        time_t now = time(NULL);
        strftime(datetime,200,"%x %X", localtime(&now));
        strcat(log,datetime);
        sendline[strlen(sendline)-1] = 0;
        strncat(log," - ",3);
        strcat(log,sendline);
        recvline[strlen(recvline)-1] = 0;
        strncat(log," - ",3);
        strcat(log,recvline);
        strncat(log,"\n",1);
        fprintf(fp,"%s",log);
```

This is the symbol I am getting with each entry

[image: This is the symbol I am getting with each entry]

How can I solve this and why is it happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`log` is uninitialized when you invoke `strcat(log,datetime);` Hence, undefined behavior.

```
    char log[200];
    char datetime[200];
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    strftime(datetime,200,"%x %X", localtime(&now));
    strcat(log,datetime);
```

Or more precisely, there's probably a garbage character in `log` as a result of being declared a stack array - picking up whatever happens to be on the stack.  The fix is simple. Change the `strcat` call to `strcpy`:

```
    strcpy(log,datetime);
```

Alternatively, you could probably make your code more efficient by using less calls to strcat and avoid redundant string copies (and potential buffer overruns).  Consider this as an alternative to what you have already written:

```
    char datetime[200];
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    strftime(datetime,200,"%x %X", localtime(&now));
    sendline[strlen(sendline)-1] = 0;
    recvline[strlen(recvline)-1] = 0;
    fprintf(fp, "%s -  %s - %s\n", datetime, sendline, recvline);
```